# Call an iframe when i change media query

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm doing a webpage, in this webpage i put an iframe whit a image,i need to change the content inside my iframe when i change the media querys, example if i'm in a `min-width 900px`, show me the `src="path/one.html"` and if im in the `in-width 1980px`, show me the `src="path/two.html"`, someone help please.

Comment: This would need to be done in Javascript. You're dynamically changing the source of an iframe. One way to do it with CSS-only is to open two iframes but hide one depending on the @media query.

Comment: any idea i do not know javascript, i appreciate the help.

Comment: Mooseman's answer is what I would do. That's using only HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iframe{
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  #iframe1{ display: inline; }
}
@media (min-width: 1980px) {
  #iframe2{ display: inline; }
}
```

and

```
<iframe src="path/one.html" id="iframe1"></iframe>
<iframe src="path/two.html" id="iframe2"></iframe>
```

Comment: Technically that isn't changing the src of the iframe but there is no other way with CSS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery you can do it this way:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){ /* resize event handler when user resizes the window */
    var windWidth =  $(window).width(); /* gets window width in pixel after resize */
    var iframe = $("#iframe1"); /* iframe dom element */

    if(windWidth >= 900 && windWidth < 1980){
        iframe.attr("src","path/one.html");  /*when window width between 900 and 1979*/
    }else if(windWidth >= 1980){  
        iframe.attr("src","path/two.html"); /*when window width 1980 and larger */
     }
})
```